# OpenMDAO parallelized sampling / why does test_brute_force.py not fail

Tags: openmdao

I modified `test_brute_force.py` in an attempt to parallelize sampling of the Paraboloid model (see code below). I get the error `'sellars': promoted name 'sellar99.p1.f_xy' matches multiple unknowns: ('sellars.sellar99.p1.f_xy', 'sellars.sellar99.p1.f_xy')`. What does this error mean? Why didn't `test_brute_force.py` face this error?

```
from __future__ import print_function
from florisse.floris import AEPGroup
import unittest

from six.moves import range
from six import iteritems
import numpy as np
from openmdao.api import Problem, Group, ParallelGroup, \
                         Component, IndepVarComp, ExecComp, \
                         Driver, ScipyOptimizer, SqliteRecorder
from openmdao.core.mpi_wrap import MPI

if MPI:
    from openmdao.core.petsc_impl import PetscImpl as impl
else:
    from openmdao.api import BasicImpl as impl

class Paraboloid(Component):
    """ Evaluates the equation f(x,y) = (x-3)^2 + xy + (y+4)^2 - 3 """

    def __init__(self):
        super(Paraboloid, self).__init__()

        self.add_param('x_p', val=6.0)
        self.add_param('y', val=-7.0)

        self.add_output('f_xy', val=0.0)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """f(x,y) = (x-3)^2 + xy + (y+4)^2 - 3
        """

        x = params['x_p']
        y = params['y']

        unknowns['f_xy'] = (x-3.0)**2 + x*y + (y+4.0)**2 - 3.0

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """ Jacobian for our paraboloid."""

        x = params['x_p']
        y = params['y']
        J = {}

        J['f_xy', 'x_p'] = 2.0*x - 6.0 + y
        J['f_xy', 'y'] = 2.0*y + 8.0 + x
        return J

pboidGroup = Group()
pboidGroup.add('p1', Paraboloid(), promotes=['x_p', 'y'])
pboidGroup.add('p2', Paraboloid(), promotes=['x_p', 'y'])
pboidGroup.connect('p1.x_p', 'p2.x_p')
pboidGroup.connect('p1.x_p', 'p2.y')

class Randomize(Component):
    """ add random uncertainty to params and distribute

    Args
    ----
    n : number of points to generate for each param

    params : collection of (name, value, std_dev) specifying the params
             that are to be randommized.
    """
    def __init__(self, n=0, params=[]):
        super(Randomize, self).__init__()

        self.dists = {}

        for name, value, std_dev in params:
            # add param
            self.add_param(name, val=value)

            # add an output array var to distribute the modified param values
            if isinstance(value, np.ndarray):
                shape = (n, value.size)
            else:
                shape = (n, 1)

            # generate a standard normal distribution (size n) for this param
            self.dists[name] = np.random.normal(0.0, std_dev, n*shape[1]).reshape(shape)
            #self.dists[name] = std_dev*np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, n*shape[1]).reshape(shape)

            self.add_output('dist_'+name, val=np.zeros(shape))

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """ add random uncertainty to params
        """
        for name, dist in iteritems(self.dists):
            unknowns['dist_'+name] = params[name] + dist

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """ derivatives
        """
        J = {}
        for u in unknowns:
            name = u.split('_', 1)[1]
            for p in params:
                shape = (unknowns[u].size, params[p].size)
                if p == name:
                    J[u, p] = np.eye(shape[0], shape[1])
                else:
                    J[u, p] = np.zeros(shape)
        return J


class Collector(Component):
    """ collect the inputs and compute the mean of each

    Args
    ----
    n : number of points to collect for each input

    names : collection of `Str` specifying the names of the inputs to
            collect and the resulting outputs.
    """
    def __init__(self, n=10, names=[]):
        super(Collector, self).__init__()

        self.names = names

        # create n params for each input
        for i in range(n):
            for name in names:
                self.add_param('%s_%i' % (name, i),  val=0.)

        # create an output for the mean of each input
        for name in names:
            self.add_output(name,  val=0.)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """ compute the mean of each input
        """
        inputs = {}

        for p in params:
            name = p.split('_', 1)[0]
            if name not in inputs:
                inputs[name] = data = [0.0, 0.0]
            else:
                data = inputs[name]
            data[0] += 1
            data[1] += params[p]

        for name in self.names:
            unknowns[name]  = inputs[name][1]/inputs[name][0]

    def linearize(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """ derivatives
        """
        J = {}
        for p in params:
            name, idx = p.split('_', 1)
            for u in unknowns:
                if u == name:
                    J[u, p] = 1
                else:
                    J[u, p] = 0
        return J


class BruteForceSellarProblem(Problem):
    """ Performs optimization on the Sellar problem.

        Applies a normal distribution to the design vars and runs all of the
        samples, then collects the values of all of the outputs, calculates
        the mean of those and stuffs that back into the unknowns vector.

        This is the brute force version that just stamps out N separate
        sellar models in a parallel group and sets the input of each
        one to be one of these random design vars.

    Args
    ----
    n : number of randomized points to generate for each input value

    derivs : if True, use user-defined derivatives, else use Finite Difference
    """
    def __init__(self, n=10, derivs=False):
        super(BruteForceSellarProblem, self).__init__(impl=impl)

        root = self.root = Group()
        if not derivs:
            root.deriv_options['type'] = 'fd'

        sellars = root.add('sellars', ParallelGroup())
        for i in range(n):
            name = 'sellar%i' % i
            sellars.add(name, pboidGroup)
            #sellars.add(name, SellarDerivatives())

            root.connect('x_p', 'sellars.'+name+'.x')#, src_indices=[i])
            #root.connect('yaw0', 'sellars.'+name+'.yaw0')#, src_indices=[i])
            #root.connect('dist_z', 'sellars.'+name+'.z', src_indices=[i*2, i*2+1])

            root.connect('sellars.'+name+'.f_xy',  'collect.obj_%i'  % i)
            #root.connect('sellars.'+name+'.con1', 'collect.con1_%i' % i)
            #root.connect('sellars.'+name+'.con2', 'collect.con2_%i' % i)

        root.add('indep', IndepVarComp([
                    ('x', 1.0),
                    ('z', np.array([5.0, 2.0]))
                ]),
                promotes=['x', 'z'])

        root.add('random', Randomize(n=n, params=[
                    # name, value, std dev
                    ('x', 1.0, 1e-2),
                    ('z', np.array([5.0, 2.0]), 1e-2)
                ]),
                promotes=['x', 'z', 'dist_x', 'dist_z'])

        root.add('collect', Collector(n=n, names=['obj', 'con1', 'con2']),
                promotes=['obj', 'con1', 'con2'])

        # top level driver setup
        self.driver = ScipyOptimizer()
        self.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
        self.driver.options['tol'] = 1.0e-8
        self.driver.options['maxiter'] = 50
        self.driver.options['disp'] = False

        self.driver.add_desvar('z', lower=np.array([-10.0,  0.0]),
                                    upper=np.array([ 10.0, 10.0]))
        self.driver.add_desvar('x', lower=0.0, upper=10.0)

        self.driver.add_objective('obj')
        self.driver.add_constraint('con1', upper=0.0)
        self.driver.add_constraint('con2', upper=0.0)

prob = BruteForceSellarProblem(100, derivs=False)
prob.setup(check=False)
prob.run()
print(prob["obj"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to model, or what should be connected to what, but I can get you past that error. The problem is that you are adding the same instance of the paraboloid group `pboidGroup` multiple times in a loop, and OpenMDAO doesn't support using the same component instance in multiple places. You need to create a new instance each time.

To fix that, i just moved the code down into the loop close to where it is used, so inside the loop we get:

```
        pboidGroup = Group()
        pboidGroup.add('p1', Paraboloid())
        pboidGroup.add('p2', Paraboloid())
        pboidGroup.connect('p1.x_p', 'p2.x_p')
        pboidGroup.connect('p1.x_p', 'p2.y')

        name = 'sellar%i' % i
        sellars.add(name, pboidGroup)
        #sellars.add(name, SellarDerivatives())
```

Now that I've done that, I get errors in the connect, and I'm not sure what x_p is meant to be in the root (maybe an IndepVarComp is needed for it), but maybe this gets you past the stoppage point.

Comment: As for what I'm trying to model, I would like to find the expected value of `f_xy` using parallelized sampling, given a normally distributed `x_p`. I added the connections to make this closer to my real problem.

Comment: Now I get the error `Source 'p1.x_p' cannot be connected to target 'sellars.sellar0.x': 'p1.x_p' does not exist.` Why doesn't a similar error appear for `dist_z` in the original example? We initialized root as an empty `Group()` I was surprised that we could reference `dist_z` without error.

Comment: So, the problem is in this line `root.connect('x_p', 'sellars.'+name+'.x')#, src_indices=[i])`.  Here, you are connecting x_p in each of the sellar systems to a source `x_p` which needs to be an output somewhere, but is not provided by anything. In the original example, we are connecting to 'dist_x', which is provided by `Randomize`.  To match up, you would either need to rename dist_x to x_p in the Randomize component or connect to `dist_x` instead. (and to do so, you'll have to uncomment the source indices)

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense now. In my real problem, I'm using FLORISSE's `AEPGroup`. I only have seen this used within a `Problem`, setting several values after `setup` is called, e.g. lines 48-62 in https://github.com/WISDEM/FLORISSE/blob/develop/test/exampleCall.py. Is there a way I can set these values to each `AEPGroup` within sellars after adding the AEPGroup in `sellars.add(name, AEPGroup(**kwargs))`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624671/openmdao-how-to-set-subgroup-properties